# How to derive an algorithms that generates check sums

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, crc

Column S contains the check sums of the values given in columns R and Xc. Does anyone here have an idea about how to find the corresponding algorithm to calculate the check sums? Thanks in advance

```
    R    Xc   S
   647   72   218
   441   47   618
   594   67   188
   581   55   517
   497   58   865
   553   65   661
   541   52   309
```

Best regards,

Holzi

Comment: This is a puzzle rather than a well-defined question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/149617/781723, http://stackoverflow.com/q/22852175/781723